# Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'AngularFireDatabase' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

Hi i'm new to angular and firebase and i've been struggling with a simple code since this morning, i've searched about the problem and I didn't find any solution that worked for me (sometimes I didn't even understand it, i'm a real beginner here)
the Error i'm having on the console is the following :

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'AngularFireDatabase' imported by the module    'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
>    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
>    at eval (compiler.js:15225)
>    at Array.forEach ()
>   at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15200)
>   at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34255)
>   at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:34216)
>   at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:34110)
>   at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:230)
>   at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:5568)
>   at eval (main.ts:11)

here's my code : 
**the app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireModule } from "angularfire2";
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase } from "angularfire2/database";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabase    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**the app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from "angularfire2/database";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

   }
}
```

**the dependencies of the package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^5.1.2",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "4.8.0",
    "ng-push": "^0.2.1",
    "ng-pwa-tools": "0.0.15",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
```

i've tried to reinstall everything many times but nothing seemed to work, I hope you guys can help me with this

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**I think yon need to change your imports to replace `AngularFireDatabase` with `AngularFireDatabaseModule`:**

```
  imports: [
    ...
    AngularFireDatabaseModule 
  ],
```

**and remove `AngularFireDatabase` from your module imports:**

```
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from "angularfire2/database";
```

you are importing `AngularFireDatabase` instead of the module. `AngularFireDatabase` should be imported in the component only.

Comment: it's finally working !! thank you you're a life saver :')

Comment: :) glad to help

Comment: Hi I have updated my project to angular latest version that is version 10 and I am getting the following error This likely means that the library (@angular/fire/firestore) which declares AngularFirestore has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if 
the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.